# find the root to not handling new lines \n \n\n in addresses

Tags: customer-address, address, billing-address

I have been searching for a bit on why I'm getting `\n` in addresses.  I have been searching in the templates, adding lines like

```
<?php echo str_replace('\\n',' ', $this->getAddressHtml(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getAddressById($_pAddsses))) ?>
```

but that is just a banded as it's coming out in the emails too.  I can't seem to find the root to the issue on this.  This is what I see everywhere

[image]

Here are some details

- In the export of the customers the address items don't have the extra `\n` in from of the address parts
- It shows up in all output that is html based
- So far all functions that return the address model outputs with `\n` when formatted in html
- shortcodes like `{{var order.getBillingAddress().format('html')}}` also have the error

Any ideas on how to root this issue out?

Comment: Do you have a store with this published somewhere ? Also what version and magento is that ?

Comment: add short code {{var order.billing_address.getFormated(\'html\')}}

Comment: @Niloct it is upto date version 1.9.2.1 and no it's not visible to the public

Comment: @PrashantValanda honestly don't see how that would help when it's ` $this->getAddressHtml(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getAddressById($_pAddsses))` if I can't sort it out I'll throw the hail marry though, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your HTML Address Template

Go to `System`->`Configuration`->`CUSTOMER`->`Customer Configuration`->`Address Templates`->`HTML` and check line endings.

[image: Address Templates]

Also you can check event `customer_address_format`. Maybe some 3rd party extension override address rendering logic.

Comment: it was rooted there.  Thank you, I swear I checked there but nope they were in there like that.  thank you